# How do I display each digit of the user's input

Tags: python

"Write a program that displays each digit of the user’s input on the screen.
Assume that the user will enter at most a 3-digit number." This is an exercise that my Prof gave me and I have no idea how to do this anybody can give me clues?

Sample Run:

```
Enter a number: 234

Hundreds = 2

Tens = 3

Ones = 4

Enter a number: 89

Hundreds = 0

Tens = 8

Ones = 9
```

Comment: Hint: use `zfill` on user input and split the resulting string. Now if you can try and post incase you have any difficulty.

Comment: A friend of mine told me to use modulo and now I have an idea what to do.

Comment: OK, re modulus: the user enters 234 and you calculate `234 % 100` or `234 % 10` what is the result? How can you use it to get your final answers?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
def reverse(num):
  rev = 0
  noplace=1
  while(num > 0):
    rev = (10*rev)+num%10
    num //= 10
    if(noplace==1)
     print Ones rev
   if(noplace==2) 
      print Tens rev
   if(noplace==3) 
      print Hundreds rev
    noplace=noplace+
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you could take, one is to treat the number entered as a string, and the other to convert the input to a number and use modulus. This shows you how it can be done using strings:

```
number = raw_input("Please enter a 3 digit number: ")
powers = ["Hundreds", "Tens", "Ones"]   
print "\n".join(["{} = {}".format(p, n) for p, n in zip(powers, number.zfill(3))])
```

The `zfill` is used to pad the text out to 3 digits in the case where only 1 or 2 digits are entered. `zip` takes a character at a time from your string, and combines it with an entry for the `powers` list. These are then formatted into a list and then printed with newlines after each entry.

This would display the following:

```
Please enter a 3 digit number: 678
Hundreds = 6
Tens = 7
Ones = 8
```